# C# with datagridview also writing lines side by side

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

**I want to show columns value side by side. Could you help?**

Code

```
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con; 
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Tablo"); 
DataRow row; 
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in name) 
{ 
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM "+item+""; 
    using (Sq1DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
    { 
        DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable(); 
        dt.Columns.Add(item.ToString());
        foreach (DataRow colRow in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row[i] = colRow.Field<String>("ColumnName").ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        i++;
    } 
} 
con.Close(); 
return dt;
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: what do you mean by side by side? please explain what do you want to do or want to achieve.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post code and describe which error you're encountering. As described, we have no clue what kind of help you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `name` is a list of columns.

It looks like you are reading the data one column at a time adding each new value as a new row. This means that you'll get a table that consists of all the first column data followed by all the second column data etc.

You either need to read all the data for each row in one call and then add that new row to your results. This is the usual method of reading data from a database.

Alternatively, when you reach the end of the first column's data start again updating the existing rows and repeating for each column.